# Get appropriate data for each row in pandas dataframe from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Lets say I have two dataframes in pandas. One `df1` contains airports with other informations and I have another dataframe `df2` which contains the location of these airports (latitutde,longitude). I would like to assign to each row in df1 the appropriate data from `df2`, how can I do that more elegantly and faster than  looping over all the possibilities? Two example image is shown below:

[Example of df1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2dwL.png)

[Example of df2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fn7a1.png)

```
    ORIGIN  DEST    DIVERTED
0   ANC     SEA     0
1   LAX     PBI     0
2   SFO     CLT     1


        IATA    LATITUDE    LONGITUDE
  17    ANC     61.17432    -149.99619
  277   SEA     47.44898    -122.30931
  176   LAX     33.94254    -118.40807
  235   PBI     26.68316    -80.09559
  278   SFO     37.619      -122.37484
  66    CLT     35.21401    -80.94313
```

Comment: Please post your dataframes as text

Comment: You need to merge your data. Probably left merge by airport name/id (whatever both dataframes have in common. If you post a small subset of the actual data as text here we can help better

Comment: Okay thanks I will post a smaller subset.

Comment: Sorry for the late update, my first post here.

Comment: See update on my answer

Comment: Give your desired output

Comment: Yes it does, just wanted to test it, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say you have the following two dataframes:

df1:

```
  IATA info1 info2 info3
0  ABI   bla   bla   bla
1  ABE   bla   bla   bla
```

df2:

```
  IATA  lat  long
0  ABE   40    90
1  ABI   20   100
```

You can use the following code to merge these two dataframes:

```
dfNew = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='IATA', how='left')
```

Output:

```
  IATA info1 info2 info3  lat  long
0  ABI   bla   bla   bla   20   100
1  ABE   bla   bla   bla   40    90
```

In your case the following will do:

```
dfNew = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on='ORIGIN', right_on='IATA', how='left').drop('IATA', axis=1)
```